# auto-text with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to use the auto text on javascript, but it does not count the spaces between the letters, the final result is "Hellotheremynameis" instead of "Hello there my name is"

```
const p = document.getElementById("text");

let index = 0;
const write = "Hello there my name is";

//auto text
function autoWrite() {
  if (index < write.length) {
    p.innerText += write.charAt(index);
    index++;
  }
}
```

Comment: `but it does not count the spaces between the letters` what do you mean? write.length is 22 symbols

Comment: "*it does not count the spaces between the letters*" Can you clarify this? Where *exactly* are you counting *anything* in the code you've posted? In any case, your code will only print the first character of your string (which seems to be counter to what you intended) as you've used `if` instead of `while`. You may find it beneficial to refresh your understanding of [Javascript's iteration concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference#Iterations).

Comment: yeah sorry, when I use the code, on the browers shows 'Hellotheremynameis' instead of 'Hello my name is'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. First, you used `if` instead of `while`. Though, you can use `if` here, but have to make the function **recursive** by calling the function after the incrementation:

   ```
   function autoWrite() {
     if (index < write.length) {
         p.innerText += write.charAt(index);
         index++;
         autoWrite();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Second problem is: you used `.innerText` which will igonre the **whitespace**. So you need to use `.innerHTML`.

   ```
   function autoWrite() {
       while (index < write.length) {
           p.innerHTML += write.charAt(index);
           index++;
       }
   }
   ```

Try this...

Comment: thanks for the explanation as well, javascript is stil a mistery to me

Comment: Take it easy and practice a lot. You will get there eventually...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop, to go through every character in the string.

```
const p = document.getElementById("text");

let index = 0;
const write = "Hello there my name is";

//auto text
function autoWrite() {
  while (index < write.length) {
    p.innerText += write.charAt(index);
    index++;
  }
}
```